# Erro na carga de dados no R

Tags: r

Estou aprendendo a mexer no `R`, e estava escrevendo um script e tudo ia bem de repente digitei

```
read.csv2.ffdf(file="DM_ALUNO.csv",sep="|",first.rows=100000)
```

apertei ctrl+r e apareceu o erro abaixo

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a logical', got '84312'
```

Alguém sabe o que fazer para solucionar ?

Comment: Não é possível dizer com certeza sem os dados, mas me parece que você tem que definir o parâmetro `colClasses` manualmente.

Comment: e como eu faço isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que a função `read.csv2`  utiliza a função `scan()`, a qual necessita que você defina qual as classes das colunas do arquivo que você está importando. Você tem duas opções, a primeira, a qual eu recomendo, é que você utilize outra função para leitura.

A função que eu utilizo por padrão para arquivos grandes é a `read_csv()` do pacote `("readr")`.

Caso você queira continuar com essa sua função você pode definir as classes com o argumento `colClasses=v`, o qual `v` é um vetor com as classes de todas as colunas do arquivo que você está lendo.

Exemplo:
caso você tenha 5 colunas no seu arquivo, a primeira como texto e as outras numéricas

```
read.csv2.ffdf(
    file="DM_ALUNO.csv",
    sep="|",
    first.rows=100000,
    colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",4))        
)
```

[Pergunta em inglês relatada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv)